How to disable opening and closing animations in the TeachingTip WinUI 3?
I want to disable the opening and closing animations for the TeachingTip. I didn't find anything which is related to animations in the default style for TeachingTip.
I checked the default style for any animations and I didn't find anything. I suspect that TeachingTipinherits from ContentControl so will it also inherit animations?.

Unfortunately, it seems that there's no easy way to do this. The control does not expose anything helpful. Might be better to create something close by yourself.
